# "birds" and "bird-strike" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I found out a few days ago that we have two tags, and the majority of questions are tagged with "birds" at the moment.

Should we change it to "bird-strike"? I would think that if a question mentions birds, it is likely about a bird strike (rather than e.g. aerodynamics of birds). "Bird strike" is a common term where people would search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that 'bird-strike' makes a better tag for that sort of question. Of the 25 questions tagged with "birds," the following are the only ones that are not related to bird strikes:

[How can seagulls slide in the wind without flapping their wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37372/1696)

[When do birds generate more lift? Take-Off or Landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36104/1696)

[What kind of g-forces do birds experience and how does it compare to humans? [closed]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34544/1696)

[Has anybody done gliding experiments with exact replicas of the birds or other real world flying creatures?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27867/1696)

At the time of posting the only one with more than 3 upvotes is the one that is closed. All but one have accepted answers. Maybe we could keep a 'birds' tag that explains it's for aerodynamics, but since those questions don't seem to come often or get great reception, I'm not opposed to doing without it.

Answer (score 11):

As fooot points out, we do have a few questions that are about birds as aviators. Even though it's only 16% of the questions in the tag, I'd prefer to avoid mistagging those with [bird-strike](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bird-strike). One complication is that a few of the [bird-strike](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bird-strike) questions are only *indirectly* about strikes: they're about bird control at airports or other related issues.

I'd be in favour of creating a new tag for the birds-as-aviators questions, maybe [bird-flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bird-flight) or [natural-flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-flight) to include things like bats too.

If we do that, we just have to decide what to do with [birds](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds). Either we should remove it completely (and re-tag all existing questions to one of the two more specific tags), or make it a synonym of one of the more specific tags. Although it makes less sense as a logical classification, I'd propose making it a synonym of [bird-strike](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bird-strike), for two reasons. First, only a small number of existing questions would have to be changed. Second, since most questions are about bird-strikes, and people tend to choose the shortest, most obvious tag, it makes sense for the short synonym to be for the most common tag: this will result in fewer mistagged questions going forward.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest having two tags:

- `bird-hazard`
- `bird-flight` or `animal-flight`

and possibly remove completely `birds` now useless.